# Arrangements of days from top to bottom intead of left to right in fulcalendar

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, fullcalendar, jquery-week-calendar

i am trying to change the arrangements of days in fullcalendar. Now days are arranged from left to right in moth, week view. i need to arrange the days from top to bottom instead of left to right.
They use tables for arranging the days .In my opinion table may not be suitable for this requirements . So i changed the table with div . Days are arranged from top to bottom ,but the events are not showing perfectly .
Anybody can help me?
Thanks in advance.

i am using the fullcalendar.js from http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/
and updated the code with my requirement

Events are shown on calendar by finding the required position based on arrangement of days from left to right . i have no idea how to modify the function to find the position of events based on top to bottom  arrangements of days.

Please give any suggestion

Answer (score 0):

You will need to modify the source code of fullcalendar.js if you want to do that. The functions provided in the documentation doesn't support you needs.